# Problem in understanding three.js coordinate and axes system

Tags: three.js

I have following code:

```
// coordinate values
var x1 = -815723.5125568421;
var y1 = 20538442.534868136;
var z1 = -17.439584224846456;
var x2 = -815723.5125568421;
var y2 = 20538443.164575472;
var z2 = -16.620415776398275;

// make a rectangular face parallel to y-z plane
var dummySquare = new THREE.Geometry();
dummySquare.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x1,y1,z1));
dummySquare.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x1,y1,z2));
dummySquare.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x2,y2,z1));
dummySquare.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x2,y2,z2));
dummySquare.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
dummySquare.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1,2,3));
var dummySquareMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "#0000FF", side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
var dummySquareMesh = new THREE.Mesh(dummySquare, dummySquareMaterial);
```

So, I am making a rectangular face parallel to y-z plane.
During debugging I observe following:

> vertices: Array(4)
>
> 0: p {x: -815723.5125568421, y: 20538442.534868136, z:
>   -17.439584224846456}
>
> 1: p {x: -815723.5125568421, y: 20538442.534868136, z:
>   -16.620415776398275}
>
> 2: p {x: -815723.5125568421, y: 20538443.164575472, z:
>   -17.439584224846456}
>
> 3: p {x: -815723.5125568421, y: 20538443.164575472, z:
>   -16.620415776398275}
>
> position: p {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}

So vertices are as expected. But position is at (0,0,0). I expected position to be mid point of the plane defined by above four vertices.

What is missing here in my understanding?

Another observation is as follows.

I make two faces just like above(same vertices).

For one of the two faces, I determine centre of geometry, move geometry it to origin(translate by negative of centre), create a mesh with it which then I move back to original position:

```
var face = new THREE.Geometry();
....add vertices as code snippet above
var faceCentre = new THREE.Vector3();
face.boundingBox.getCenter(faceCentre );
face.translate(-faceCentre .x,-faceCentre .y,-faceCentre .z);
//make mesh
var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "#FF0000", side: 
THREE.DoubleSide } );
var faceMesh= new THREE.Mesh(face, faceMaterial);
// move mesh back by setting its position to original centre of face
faceMesh.position.x = faceCentre .x;
faceMesh.position.y = faceCentre .y;
faceMesh.position.z = faceCentre .z;
```

Unmoved face has same vertices as for face above, as expected.

But other face has now totally different vertices, even though both are displayed at same position and in same orientation.

Why this difference in vertices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THREE.js uses a hierarchical representation of objects and their translation. In particular, the `.position` of an `Object3D` is not generally, as you say you expected, its middle point in world space, but it can be viewed as a variable that stores the current translation of the object. It is called its *local* position. This translation is `(0,0,0)` on default.

So when you define an object by the vertices of its geometry, the object's vertices will render at these positions. However, if you `.translate()` it by a factor `(dx, dy, dz)`, then a vertex `(vx, vy, vz)` will render at position `(vx+dx, vy+dy, vz+dz)`.

Similarly, other transformations are also stored as members of the object. The vertices of the geometry do not change when an object is transformed, but instead the object keeps track of its current *local* transformations, which are applied, typically as a series of matrix multiplications, to the vertices. Using this logic, you can define a tree of objects inside each other, which have local transformations in relation to its parent, which in turn may be transformed in relation to its parent etc. This sort of representation proves very useful for slightly more complicated scenes.

This should explain your results. For example, in your first test, you are successfully creating an object exactly where you want it, but its `position` is still (0,0,0) because it has undergone no transformations.

Comment: Which coordinate system are vertices expressed?
I made a cube as:

Comment: When you define a geometry, its vertices are expressed in a local coordinate system. When you place an object directly in your scene, at position p, then a vertex v in your object will be rendered on position p+v. I.e., the local coordinate system of your object is translated by p. In particular, the mesh does not change, only the transformations that the object keeps track of do

Comment: Thanks for this reply. So it means while vertices are expressed in object's local coordinate system(v), while object's position(p) is expressed in global coordinate system. So in global coordinate system, a vertice becomes p+v(basic vector algebra rule). Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have doubt though. When I do geometry.translate(), why doesn't it change object.position? Shouldn't an object's position be determined by its vertices value?

Comment: Ah, I think the main source for confusion here is this: A geometry in THREE.js does not represent an object in the scene. It represents a shape of some sort. You can create a geometry and then assign that same geometry to several objects, all placed in the scene under different translations (or other transformations, e.g. rotation or scale). The underlying geometry will be the same, but the different "copies" may have undergone different transformations.

Comment: That hits the bull's eye. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Just an observation.. When I do new THREE.BoxGeometry(5,5,5), I see geometry's vertices like: 2.5,2.5,2.5(with appropriate +- sign). Going by definition of a geometry, it seems a bit odd as it gives an impression as if this geometry is defined wrt some origin.

Comment: Well in that case, it's just because `BoxGeometry` is defined like that: Symmetrical (over each axis) wrt. the local (0,0,0). Of course the vertices of a geometry can be located anywhere in 3D space but it is generally useful to define them so that the local origin has some meaning. Thus if you were to place an object with this geometry directly in your scene and translate it by (2.5,2.5,2.5), it should render with one corner in the world origin. If you don't translate, then local and global coordinates are aligned and it will indeed render centered around world origin.